# Does vscode have spell check in git commit message box?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wonder if vscode have a spell checker for commit message box, I think it would be very useful to check spell mistakes before committing.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not as of VS Code 1.18. Please file a feature request: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Answer (score 13):

Please vote and comment on https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35571 to make it happen.

Answer (score 8):

### Update (March 2024)

You no longer need to update any of your user settings. All that's needed to get this working is to have the [Code Spell Checker plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker) installed.

Thanks @cyreb7 for sharing this.

(Old answer below...)

---

### This is 100% possible as of December 2022.

This is now possible (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35571 has been closed).

However, it seems to require the de-facto spell checking extension (which you may already use). And it requires an addition to its configuration.

### Steps to get spell checking to work in VS Code's commit message box

1. Install the [cSpell plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker)
2. Add `csminput` to the `cSpell.enabledLanguageIds` array (either via the settings-editor UI or directly in your user-settings JSON file). E.g.

   ```js
   "cSpell.enabledLanguageIds": [
      "scminput",
      // ...
   ],
   ```
3. That's all! You should now be able to write commit messages without spelling errors

Comment: Heads up that you no longer need to edit any user settings, Git commit spell checking is enabled by default when you install the current version of Code Spell Checker.

Comment: @cyreb7 This is really great news! Thanks for sharing here. Will update the answer to point this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a separate editor to write the commit message (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72394972/836330 for how to do that) then various spell checkers do work in that editor.

> In the latest Insiders release (2022-06-27), if you click on the
> commit button without a commit message, a full editor will open that
> can be used as an input for the commit message. This has the side
> effect that any spellchecker extensions will work in the commit
> message editor as well.
>
> Next milestone, I will also look into the possibility of leveraging
> the built-in spellchecker or exposing the document behind the SCM
> Input so that spellchecker extensions can get access to the document,
> and provide markers for words that are mistyped.

From https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/35571

At least a couple of spell checkers have been reported there as working in the commit message editor.