# Edit git commit message in a dedicated tab

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

As an Atom user, I am used that when committing staged changes a new buffer is opened where I can edit the commit message. In particular, the advantages are:

- existing spell check is available
- I can provide a one line comment and an additional longer description
- I see a list of files to be committed (similar to the case when using the CLI)

What is the vscode equivalent? So far I found two options:

1. `Command Palette -> Git: commit (staged)`
2. Use the activity bar (where I see the staged files but still get a limited editing option of the commit message)

Answer (score 3):

You could always specify VSCode as the editor to use when running `git commit` from the command line.

VSCode even has the `--wait` option : it waits until you close *the opened buffer* (not until you quit VSCode) :

```
GIT_EDITOR='code --wait' git commit
```

The main downside is that I don't know how to target a specific instance of VSCode to use if I have several open.

Answer (score 0):

A full editor can be used as git commit message editor, see [v1.69 release notes: Author commit message using an editor](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_69.md#author-commit-message-using-an-editor).

> Use the full text editor to author your commit message. To accept the
> commit message and complete the commit operation you can either close
> the editor tab or select the `Accept Commit Message` button in the
> editor toolbar. To cancel the commit operation, you can either clear
> the contents of the text editor and close the editor tab, or select
> the `Discard Commit Message` button in the editor toolbar.
>
> You can disable this new flow, and fallback to the previous experience
> that uses the quick input control, by toggling the
> `git.useEditorAsCommitInput` setting. After the setting is changed, you
> will have to restart VS Code for the change to take effect.
>
> To leverage the same flow for git commit commands that executed in the
> integrated terminal, enable the git.terminalGitEditor setting. After
> enabling the setting, you will have to restart your terminal session.

Steps to enable:

1. Enable the setting: `Git: Use Editor as Commit Input`
2. Optionally, enable: `Git: Verbose Commit`
3. With an *empty commit message input box`trigger one of the commands that sends an commit, like`Git: Commit`or`Git: Commit All`.

You can also hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> with focus in the empty commit message input.

[There is a bug in testing this right now (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150463).  There is an mp4 of it working at the link above. though.]